# rviz can not send goal to move_base from another computer

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am running a car-like robot. I have an move_base node with global/local planner, and I can send goal from rviz to move the car. Now, I want to run the rviz from another computer. Everything works fine, I can see the tf, laser scan etc in rviz. But when I sent the goal with "2D Nav Goal" in rviz from another computer, the car did not move. The car did not get the goal message either when I run "rostopic echo".

Why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298933/rviz-can-not-send-goal-to-move_base-from-another-computer/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-07-28

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is most likely a ROS network setup issue. Please try to lookup some earlier questions about topics showing up / being visible, but not being able to receive/send any messages (#q298655 being a very recent one).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1